# What's the equivalent way of writing inline assignment and checking PHP 'logic' but in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, comparison

In PHP you could write this:

```
if(false !== ($value = someFunctionCall())) {
 // use $value
}
```

How would you write an equivalent of this in JavaScript without defining

```
var value;
```

before this comparison?

Comment: You would not. An inline assignment (as a part of an expression) is different from a variable declaration. So, without using a global `value` variable, you can't.

Comment: BTW, some-what related given the question: [Difference between using var and not using var in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You'd write

```
if (value = someFunction()) {
```

I don't trust my knowledge of PHP that heavily, but I suspect that explicit comparisons to `false` in `if` statements aren't necessary, as the expression is implicitly boolean. (*edit* — sometimes, if a function can return either an explicit boolean *or* some "good" value that evaluates to "falsy", then yes you do need the explicit comparison to boolean.)

*edit* — if you're squeamish about the ages-old confusion (or potential thereof) between `=` and `==`, then I'd advise avoiding the construct entirely.  There's nothing wrong with it, other than the fact that sometimes you want an equality comparison and sometimes you want an assignment.

*edit* oh also this presumes that "value" has been declared with `var` *somewhere* — if the question is about how you do the *declaration* in the context of an `if` statement, then the answer is that you cannot do that.

*final edit I kind-of promise* — to sum it up:

*Assuming* that "value" is declared:

```
var value;
```

somewhere, then:

```
if (false !== (value = someFunction())) { ... }
```

has pretty much the same semantics as the PHP original.

Comment: that would be very bad practice

Comment: I could write the above and not get a failure, but I would get an warning.  That's the condition I'm attempting to work around.

Comment: @LiamMcCann bad practice?  Well, you could explicitly "booleanize" it I suppose.

Comment: Yea that would be better, what im trying to say is if you do var value and its been used before it would error, but if you dont var it and value has been used before it would change the value of value and could cause issues other places in the code... Good answer though !

Comment: @LiamMcCann ah thanks - I've amended the answer to point out that the actual *declaration* of the variable has to happen before the `if` statement somewhere.

Comment: @Pointy: The `===` exists for a reason. Suppose `if (!($a = strpos('foo','foobar')))` vs. directly comparing for `false`. (`strpos` would return a falsy `0`, however 0+ would be an acceptable result.)

Comment: @BradChristie yes I understand that it's sometimes necessary, though (since we're on the general topic here :-) it seems like there's a code smell somewhere around that.  You're right however, sometimes it really is necessary to check for an explicit boolean.

Comment: The above PHP allows for a default condition of exactly false, but 0 or other values may be returned if not false.  In JS, I wasn't sure if you could write a similarly compact check and assign without setting a variable somewhere first with var x=y;

Comment: @MyStream OK I see what you're getting at - yes, and it would look almost exactly the same - JavaScript has `!==` with pretty much the same meaning.

Comment: I think the simple answer is that it can't be done with an IF, can be done with FOR, can't be done with WHILE

Answer (score 0):

You can just have it assign when it's executed and JavaScript will automatically add the `var` declaration:

```
function foo(){
    return (Math.random() * 0.5) > 0;
}
if (false !== (f = foo())){
    alert('True!');
}
alert('f=' + f.toString());
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7Vwsb/)

**However**, this is very bad practice. You should **always** declare your variables when and where you need them first. Just because PHP and JS accept this syntax doesn't mean it's good practice. The proper style would be as follows:

```
var f = false;
if (false !== (f = foo())){
    alert('True!');
}
alert('f=' + f.toString());
```

Comment: I'm looking at dependency injection.  I don't have a problem defining them, just looking for a more compact way to write a statement and wasn't aware if there was one.

Comment: There is no automatically inserted variable declaration, that's Coffeescript. In JS, this would use a global variable.

Comment: @Bergi: I never implied where it would scope the variable, just that JS acknowledges it should be a variable and declares it (implicitly).

Comment: So, in essence, it's not possible to formulate an inline assignment as part of something like while or if/else or switch. It has to be done before hand regardless.

Comment: @MyStream: Yes. The only block I'm aware of where JS allows declaration within (without getting in to code practices) is the `for`: `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){ /* i */ }`. Other than that, declare before use is necessary. Again, all is dependent on how readable you want code and if you care about good practices. (**EDIT**: If you _really_ want to get in to it, PHP and JS are alike in terms of variable declarations [less the var keyword])

Comment: It was this condition I had in mind.  For allows it, but IF didn't appear to, so I was curious.  The condition usually allows for statements to be single-lined where the variable is created, assigned and compared and then used in that block and usually unnecessary in the else block, but it means, in php, that you create only at the last moment, and only if you need that space set aside rather than defining a lot of variables up front for all possible conditions that might follow.  Use cases determine usability, but some cases make it a very readable php alternative, not necessarily js, perhaps

Comment: @MyStream: From my perspective (and I agree about not declaring everything up-front, but only to an extent) a variable should be defined but only where it's scope is beginning (essentially adhering to [block scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Block_scope_within_a_function)). However, I will never let a condition declare the variable for me. A good example is [this](http://ideone.com/Emt2c).

Answer (score -1):

That would be very bad practice in JavaScript,

You would be best to do

```
if(!(var value = someFunctionCall())) { // use value //}
```

Personally i would say define it before. Your call though. If you worried about memory then define it and null it after use.

Comment: Implementation notwithstanding `null` does not take less memory than `false` in JavaScript. You can, however, use the `delete` keyword to remove a variable from memory.

Comment: @Jordan: That's not how to use delete as well. This keyword is designed for properties only.